# How bootstrap work correctly in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am first to learn laravel 5.2 about one week. and I try to learn larevel from youtube and document laravel .but I wonder They teach and just copy templat bootstrap without download bootstrap file to put into folder public it works, but when I try to follow theme it not work for me ,but when I download bootstrap file and put into public folder and call it work for. My problam I want to know how bootstrap work correctly in laravel .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create the blade template and then in template put the link of bootstrap.

Example (index.blade.php) CDN links:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Title</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Here you can put your content -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Example (index.blade.php) local links:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Title</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="http://yoursite/public/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Here you can put your content-->
<script src="http://yoursite/public/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think use a absolute url with localhost as domain is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Another way to get that done is to get bootstrap from npm if you prefer working offline, plus laravel 5 comes with gulp and a package.json file by default 

    1. add the following to your package to json 

    {
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.8.8",
        "laravel-elixir": "^2.0.0",
        "jquery": "latest",
        "bootstrap": "latest"
      }
    }

    2. npm install that  would get the latest verion of bootstrap and jquery which is required, if you encounter any error if on linux do sudo npm install

    3. mix the css and javascript file with laravel elixir by have below declarations in your gulpfile.js


    var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

    var nodeDir = './node_modules/';

    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Elixir Asset Management
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
     | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
     | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
     |
     */
    elixir(function(mix) {
    //mix css first and copy the needed fonts

    //mix.css('app.css', 'public/css',)
        mix.styles([
            'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
        ], './public/css/app.css', nodeDir)
            .copy(nodeDir + 'font-awesome/fonts', 'public/fonts')
            .copy(nodeDir + 'bootstrap/fonts', 'public/fonts');

    //mix javascript

        mix.scripts([
            'jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'

        ], './public/js/app.js', nodeDir);


    });

    run gulp

    $ gulp

    finally a welcome.blade.php

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">

        <title>Fixed Top Navbar Example for Bootstrap</title>        
    </head>

    <body cz-shortcut-listen="true">

    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>

    </body>
    </html>

    The above reduces number of http request you make to load bootstrap bootstrap and its dependency jquery

reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir

    Hope this helps
```

Answer (score -1):

Laravel is a server side framework. It should handles database, caches, logs and validation.
Bootstrap is a client side UI framework. It should handles UI component like tabs, grid, forms and some typography aspects.

Every server side framework supports every client side framework, so feel free to use Laravel with Bootstrap.

In particular you should create a base layout with some common html and extend it in your different views. In this base layout you have to include Bootstrap via CDN or locally using asset() helper. This helper helps you to build url (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers).

Comment: Thank you bro for answer